# Can not install react-native-ssl-pinning manually on IOS

Tags: react-native, sslpinning

I use react-native 0.71.8. I install react-native-ssl-pinning, It worked well on Android, but on IOS, It throw error: URL unsupport or The certificate for this server is not valid. You may be connecting to a server posing as “****.com”, which could jeopardize your security information.

It seems that react-native-ssl-pinning does not auto install in IOS, I followed step in readme to install manually, but It throw this error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5svJ.png)

React-native-ssl-pinning can work on IOS